# How do I set the first and last frame of a video to be an image?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing

HTML 5 implementations are different across various browsers.  In firefox, the image specified by the placeholder attribute will be shown until the user clicks play on the video.  In chrome, the placeholder image is shown until the video is loaded (not played), at which point the first frame of the video is shown.

To reconcile this issue, I would like to set the first frame of the video to the placeholder image so that the experience will be the same in both browsers.

I would preferably do this using ffmpeg or mencoder.  I have very limited experience using these however, so if someone could point me in the right direction, I would be much obliged.

Thanks!

Comment: First of all you have to calculate the length of the video the detailed description is here http://vipinkrsahu.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-make-video-streaming-sites-like.html